# How to disable ipv4 address stack in jboss EAP 6.4.0 server

Tags: jboss-eap-6

I am using jboss eap 6.4.0 server with dual address stack network environment (network supporting both ipv4 and ipv6 address).

I want to disable ipv4 address stack from eap server side. For this, I have updated standalone.xml with below changes ---

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.policy-permissions=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true"
```

In above code, I have made two changes -- [1] -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false" and [2] -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true"

After that I am running command -

```
./standalone.sh -b ::
```

I am using -b :: so that server can listen to my linux machine's ipv6 address.

Above configuration is not working, here. I am able to reach to server's public page with both ipv6 and ipv4 address.

Ipv4 address stack is not getting blocked with the above configuration.

Please help!!

Thanks 
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Disable the IPv4 Stack Java Property:

1. Open the relevant file for the installation

   A.For a Standalone Server:
    Open EAP_HOME/bin/standalone.conf.

   B.For a Managed Domain:
    Open EAP_HOME/bin/domain.conf.

2.Change the IPv4 Stack Java property to false:
  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false

For example:

#Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false 
   -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 
   -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true"
fi

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have already tried the solution that you have mentioned but it is not working. Also when I start the server, I can see that ipv4 property is set to false and ipv6 property is set to true. I am using linux system. Does this configuration works in linux system, too?